# Misuning simpler regex format?

Tags: regex, simple-form-for

So I am working on a fraction class for school and am using a regex pattern and matcher for user input. I found this online so i'll admit im not exactly sure what does what, but the following pattern finds each digit, middle operation, and allows spaces and tabs between all characters of the user's input(a fraction expression).

```
String fractionPattern = "\\s*\\t*\\\\*t*(-?\\d+)\\s*\\t*\\\\*t*\\/\\s*\\t*\\\\*t*(-?\\d+)\\s*\\t*\\\\*t*([-+*/])\\s*\\t*\\\\*t(\\d+)\\s*\\t*\\\\*t*\\/\\s*\\t*\\\\*t*(-?\\d+)\\s*\\t*\\\\*t*";
```

I've tried researching java regex metacharacters and symbol meanings, but I am sort of struggling. Can someone offer me an explanation on each character? Or possibly a simpler way of accomplishing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

So you're looking to match fractions? Like `"2 / 3"` or whatever, and allow spaces? If so, you want to match (and capture) some string of digits, then a `'/'` character, then match and capture another string of digits. Without considering spaces, this is just:

```
"(\\d+)/(\\d+)"
```

`\d` in a regex matches any digit (0-9), but since we specify regexes with Strings, we have to escape the backslash itself. That is, the Java string literal "\" results in a String object with one backslash character.
The `+` means "one or more", and the parentheses capture it. Then the slash is just a literal slash.
To make it allow spaces, match and discard any space. \s matches any type of space (space, tab, newline), and again we have to escape the backslash:

```
"(\\d+)\\s*/\\s*(\\d+)"
```

`*` means "zero or more". So from left to right, this means:

1. One or more digits, which are captured

   Zero or more spaces

   A literal slash

   Zero or more spaces

   One or more digits, which are captured

   To handle whitespace on the ends, either match space there, or
   trim() the string first.

Answer (score 0):

The regex pattern you posted actually matches any operation between *two* fractions.

There is a lot of noise in there with extra `\t` (tab) characters (which is redundant with `\s` for whitespace). Removing those and changing the double backslash to single backslash for readability, we get the following:

```
\s*(-?\d+)\s*\/\s*(-?\d+)\s*([-+*/])\s*(\d+)\s*\/\s*(-?\d+)\s*
```

(Double backslash is needed when the regex is in a String, so it is not treated as an [escape sequence](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/escape-sequences-in-java))

Let's break it down:

- `\s*` means match 0 or more whitespace characters
- `-?` means match one `-` character or none, for negative numbers
- `\d+` means match 1 or more numbers (0-9)
- The parentheses around `(-?\d+)` means we can capture this first number and refer to it later if we want to.
- `\s*` means 0 or more whitespace characters again
- `\/` means match `/` literally. Some languages / regex parsers require the backslash in front of a forward slash. Others (like Python) do not.
- `\s*(-?\d+)\s*` is the same thing we just did with the first number, again: get another (possibly negative) number, potentially surrounded by whitespace, and capture it with parentheses for later use.
- `([-+/])` means match any of `-`, `+`, or `/`: the operation we want to perform between the two fractions. Parentheses are optional, only needed if you want to grab this character later.
- `\s*(\d+)\s*\/\s*(-?\d+)\s*` is again what we had with the first fraction, except for some reason the possible negative sign is not included in the numerator, which is probably a mistake.

You can test it out [here](https://regex101.com/r/I6dXTx/2). (Regex101 is your friend.)